# how to align block in an irregular way

Tags: css, sass, flexbox, responsive-design, grid

As in the attached photo I want to align block with text in that way so I can't use flexbox as it would align every 2 blocks in a horizontal space not like the photo attatched .

So can somebody tell me  a possible way to do it taking the responsive design into consideration .[image]

Comment: need more clarification to the query, as to what is the problem area and what should the desired solution look like